# pysnmp throwing UnknownCommunityName error

Tags: pysnmp

I have a pcap file containing 4 SNMP trap packets. When I replay the packets through pysnmp, it throws error as

```
DBG: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownCommunityName instance at 0x2023248>}
```

I have configured PySNMP to accept packets having community name as 'public'.

```
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'agent', 'public')
```

When I see the packet in WireShark, it is showing community name as public but debugging through PySNMP I found that the community name is in OctetString (equivalent to public in ASCII). What should I do now?

p.s. Unix's snmptrapd works correctly in the given pcap file.

Pysnmp Version: 4.3.1 
Pyasn1 version: 0.1.9

**Edit**
Here is full stacktrace in debug mode

```
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42174 2016-01-12 04:45:45,421 pysnmp: handle_read: transportAddress ('192.168.2.17', 162) -> ('0.0.0.0', 162) incomingMessage (70 octets) 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42179 00000: 30 82 00 42 02 01 00 04 07 70 75 62 6C 69 63 00 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42179 00016: A4 34 06 08 2B 06 01 04 01 90 7A 01 40 04 0A 62 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42180 00032: 21 64 02 01 03 02 01 00 43 04 54 10 5A 06 30 16 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42180 00048: 30 82 00 12 06 0D 2B 06 01 04 01 90 7A 01 02 01 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42181 00064: 01 01 02 02 01 02
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42182 DEBUG: handle_read: transportAddress ('192.168.2.17', 162) -> ('0.0.0.0', 162) incomingMessage (70 octets) 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42182 00000: 30 82 00 42 02 01 00 04 07 70 75 62 6C 69 63 00 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42183 00016: A4 34 06 08 2B 06 01 04 01 90 7A 01 40 04 0A 62 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42183 00032: 21 64 02 01 03 02 01 00 43 04 54 10 5A 06 30 16 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42183 00048: 30 82 00 12 06 0D 2B 06 01 04 01 90 7A 01 02 01 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42184 00064: 01 01 02 02 01 02
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42369 2016-01-12 04:45:45,423 pysnmp: receiveMessage: msgVersion 0, msg decoded
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42381 DEBUG: receiveMessage: msgVersion 0, msg decoded
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42587 2016-01-12 04:45:45,425 pysnmp: prepareDataElements: Message:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42598  version='version-1'
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42606  community=0x7075626c696300
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42614  data=PDUs:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42621   trap=TrapPDU:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42628    enterprise=1.3.6.1.4.1.2170.1
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42636    agent-addr=NetworkAddress:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42643     internet=10.98.33.100
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42650 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42657    generic-trap='linkUp'
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42664    specific-trap=0
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42673    time-stamp=1410357766
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42683    variable-bindings=VarBindList:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42685     VarBind:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42685      name=1.3.6.1.4.1.2170.1.2.1.1.1.2
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42686      value=ObjectSyntax:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42686       simple=SimpleSyntax:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42686        number=2
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42687 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42687 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42688 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42688 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42689 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42697 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42697 DEBUG: prepareDataElements: Message:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42698  version='version-1'
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42698  community=0x7075626c696300
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42699  data=PDUs:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42699   trap=TrapPDU:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42699    enterprise=1.3.6.1.4.1.2170.1
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42700    agent-addr=NetworkAddress:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42700     internet=10.98.33.100
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42701 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42701    generic-trap='linkUp'
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42701    specific-trap=0
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42702    time-stamp=1410357766
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42702    variable-bindings=VarBindList:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42703     VarBind:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42703      name=1.3.6.1.4.1.2170.1.2.1.1.1.2
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42710      value=ObjectSyntax:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42720       simple=SimpleSyntax:
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42720        number=2
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42721 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42721 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42721 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42722 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42722 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42723 
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42724 2016-01-12 04:45:45,426 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownCommunityName instance at 0x2ce9680>}
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42731 DEBUG: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownCommunityName instance at 0x2ce9680>}
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42734 2016-01-12 04:45:45,426 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownCommunityName instance at 0x2ce9680>}
2016-01-12_04:45:45.42735 DEBUG: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.UnknownCommunityName instance at 0x2ce9680>}
```

Problem exists for only one agent. Trap coming from all other agents are processed normally.

Comment: OctetString object you observe should work. Make sure you are using the latest pysnmp. I suspect it has something to do with 'transport tags'. Debug output might help resolving this issue.

Comment: @llya Etingof I have updated my question with log view. Can you say anything about the problem seeing the debug log??

Comment: I have also upgraded pysnmp to latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when you are building PDU from a dumped (?) packet, you include trailing zero to SNMP community string value.

```
>>> from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import *
>>> OctetString(hexValue='7075626c696300').asOctets()
'public\x00'
```

If that's what you want make sure to configure pysnmp accordingly.

```
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'agent', 'public\x00')
```

or

```
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'agent', OctetString(hexValue='7075626c696300'))
```

Comment: Great !! Agent itself is sending trap with community string with training zero. You saved my day :)